# How to use value of GrandChild in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to use the value of the grandchild provided. I tried but was unable to fetch the value of the grandchild.

This is the xml provided to me

```
<InvoiceDocument>
<Invoice>
<d>100</d>
<a>120</a>
<Products>
<Product>
<b>11<b>
<c>12</c>
</Product>
<Product>
<b>13</b>
<c>14</c>
</Product>
</Products>
</Invoice>
</InvoiceDocument>
```

This is the format of xml that i require

```
<MessageParts>
<LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
<e>120</e>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity'>
<g>11</g>
<h>12</h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity'>
<g>13</g>
<h>14</h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
</LedgerJournalTable>
</MessageParts>
```

This is the code through which i tried fetching the value of grandchild.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="InvoiceDocument">
    <MessageParts>
    <LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice"/>
    <LedgerJournalTrans class="entity'>
    <xsl:for-each select="Product">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </LedgerJournalTrans>
    </LedgerJournalTable>
    </MessageParts>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Invoice">
  <e><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[1])"/></e>
  </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="Product">
  <g><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(b/text()[1])"/></g>
  <h><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(c/text()[1])"/></h>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, but there's a couple things here:

- Nest the Product apply templates inside the Invoice template, in order to apply it recursively
- You don't need the imperative style `xsl-foreach` - `apply-templates` is the better approach.
- There's a couple typos in the xml with closing elements `/b` and in your xsl quotes `class="entity'`
- There is a `Products` element which wraps `Product`

Here's one way to do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="InvoiceDocument">
    <MessageParts>
      <LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice"/>
      </LedgerJournalTable>
    </MessageParts>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Invoice">
       <e><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[1])"/></e>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Products/Product"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product">
      <LedgerJournalTrans class="entity">
         <g><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(b/text()[1])"/></g>
         <h><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(c/text()[1])"/></h>
      </LedgerJournalTrans>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Working fiddle here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSuP/1)

Comment: Can i use the Product template directly in the InvoiceDocument Template without having to use it inside the Invoice Template.

Comment: Its generally better XSL practice to "DRY" up the templates into focussed concerns, where each template concentrates on a particular section of the projected output. But yes, if you really wanted to, you could replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="Products/Product"/>` with `<xsl:for-each select="Products/Product"/>` and then inline the `Product` template (and could do the same thing at top leve). But that looks smelly and imperative.

Comment: I cannot use it under invoice Template, i need to use it in the InvoiceDocument template under <LedgerJournalTrans class="Entity">

Comment: Then you haven't posted a [Minimum Reproducible Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My answer [does exactly what you've stated that you want](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSuP/1).

Comment: Shall i post another question or edit my question itself